# how to combine more than one query in same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE studenttest 
(
    YEAR INT,
    DEPT VARCHAR(5),
    SEM INT,
    REGNO INT,
    NAME VARCHAR(20),
    ENGLISH VARCHAR(2),
    MATHS VARCHAR(2),
    PHYSICS VARCHAR(2),
    CHEMISTRY VARCHAR(2),
    EG VARCHAR(2),
    FOC VARCHAR(2),
    LAB1 VARCHAR(2),
    LAB2 VARCHAR(2),
    LAB3 VARCHAR(2)
)
```

With the following data:

```
INSERT INTO studenttest 
 values
 (2010,'cse',3,1,'saravaanan','a','b','c','d','ra','f','g','h','i'),   
 (2010,'cse',3,2,'raja','ra','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i'),
 (2010,'cse',3,3,'selvam','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i')
```

I want to query this data to get the result set of all the students who do not have a grade of "ra" in *any* of the subjects.

Comment: Don't ever be sorry to ask. So how will you learn?!

Comment: @MahmoudGamal - I deleted that part of the OP - without questions `SO` would be a sad place

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    studenttest a
        LEFT JOIN
        (
          SELECT regno, name
          FROM studenttest
          WHERE ENGLISH = 'ra' OR
                MATHS = 'ra' OR
                PHYSICS = 'ra' OR
                CHEMISTRY    = 'ra' OR
                EG  = 'ra' OR   
                FOC = 'ra' OR   
                LAB1 = 'ra' OR  
                LAB2 = 'ra' OR  
                LAB3 = 'ra'
        ) b ON a.regno = b.regno 
               AND a.Name = b.Name   -- this line is OPTIONAL
WHERE   b.regno IS NULL
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/655a0/5)

Comment: Just for curiosity, which one is better for performance wise this query or Mahmoud Gamal's query..

Comment: @satindersingh it depends on how the table was index. see the execution plan.

Answer (score 4):

Just an an alternative to [@Mahmoud's version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14079388/how-to-combine-more-than-one-query-in-same-table/14079442#14079442) with the `UNPIVOT` and the `CTE`, this can also be done using a `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT Name
FROM
(
  SELECT Name, ENGLISH grade, 'English' subject
  from studenttest
  union all
  SELECT Name, MATHS grade, 'MATHS' subject
  from studenttest
  union all
  SELECT Name, PHYSICS grade, 'PHYSICS' subject
  from studenttest
  union all
  SELECT Name, CHEMISTRY grade, 'CHEMISTRY' subject
  from studenttest
  union all
  SELECT Name, EG grade, 'EG' subject
  from studenttest
  union all
  SELECT Name, FOC grade, 'FOC' subject
  from studenttest
  union all
  SELECT Name, LAB1 grade, 'LAB1' subject
  from studenttest
  union all
  SELECT Name, LAB2 grade, 'LAB2' subject
  from studenttest
  union all
  SELECT Name, LAB3 grade, 'LAB3' subject
  from studenttest
) un
where grade <> 'ra'
group by name
having count(grade) = 9
```

The `UNPIVOT` is performing the same step that the `UNION ALL` does with less code. These queries work great when you have data that is not normalized like your table is.

If you then want all of the data (not just names) you can rejoin the above query to the table again:

```
select *
from studenttest t
inner join
(
  SELECT Name
  FROM
  (
    SELECT Name, ENGLISH grade, 'English' subject
    from studenttest
    union all
    SELECT Name, MATHS grade, 'MATHS' subject
    from studenttest
    union all
    SELECT Name, PHYSICS grade, 'PHYSICS' subject
    from studenttest
    union all
    SELECT Name, CHEMISTRY grade, 'CHEMISTRY' subject
    from studenttest
    union all
    SELECT Name, EG grade, 'EG' subject
    from studenttest
    union all
    SELECT Name, FOC grade, 'FOC' subject
    from studenttest
    union all
    SELECT Name, LAB1 grade, 'LAB1' subject
    from studenttest
    union all
    SELECT Name, LAB2 grade, 'LAB2' subject
    from studenttest
    union all
    SELECT Name, LAB3 grade, 'LAB3' subject
    from studenttest
  ) un
  where grade <> 'ra'
  group by name
  having count(grade) = 9
) t2
  on t.name = t2.name
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/72d0e/21)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
WITH AllSubjectsGrades
AS
(
  SELECT Name, Grade
  FROM
  (
    SELECT 
      Name, 
      ENGLISH, MATHS, PHYSICS,  CHEMISTRY,
      EG,  FOC, LAB1, LAB2, LAB3
    FROM studenttest
  ) t
  UNPIVOT
  (
    grade
    FOR Subject IN(ENGLISH, MATHS, PHYSICS, CHEMISTRY,
                   EG,  FOC, LAB1, LAB2, LAB3)
  ) u
)
SELECT Name
FROM AllSubjectsGrades
WHERE GRADE <> 'ra'
GROUP BY Name
HAVING COUNT(GRADE) = 9;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/72d0e/12)

This will give you only the student `selvam`, since `saravaanan` has the 'ra' in the `EG` and `raja` has 'ra' in English. But `selvam` has never got `ra` in any subject. And thats what

```
GROUP BY Name
HAVING COUNT(GRADE) = 9;
```

Do.

Comment: +1 as this script demonstrates some nice techniques. Although compared to @JW script it is very complicated.

Comment: @whytheq - It is not complicated if you know about the `UNPIVOT` operator, which did the whole work.

Comment: it's not complicated if you understand `CTE` and `UNPIVOT` + OP does not say which version of SQL-Server - is it late enough version for `CTE` ? ....but it is very good to give user exposure to these parts of `tsql`

Comment: @whytheq this is the same as performing a `UNION ALL` query which is sometimes easier to understand -- see my [answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14079388/how-to-combine-more-than-one-query-in-same-table/14082244#14082244)

Comment: @bluefeet - in your comment you say "see my answer below" and it has a hyperlink to the exact location of your answer; page scrolled. How do you do this?

Comment: @whytheq I just added a hyperlink directly to my answer.

Comment: @bluefeet oh - let me test - if you follow [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14094327/how-to-combine-these-two-sql-statements/14094540#14094540) ....do you go to a page with my attempt at the top of the browser?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean this?

```
SELECT * 
FROM studenttest
WHERE 
    ENGLISH <> 'ra' AND
    MATHS <> 'ra' AND
    PHYSICS <> 'ra' AND
    CHEMISTRY    <> 'ra' AND
    EG  <> 'ra' AND   
    FOC <> 'ra' AND   
    LAB1 <> 'ra' AND  
    LAB2 <> 'ra' AND
    LAB3 <> 'ra'
```

Answer (score 2):

One more way:

```
SELECT * 
FROM studenttest
WHERE 'ra' NOT IN 
      (ENGLISH, MATHS, PHYSICS, CHEMISTRY, EG, FOC, LAB1, LAB2, LAB3) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM studenttest
WHERE ENGLISH + ',' + MATHS + ',' + PHYSICS + ',' + CHEMISTRY + ',' + EG + ',' + FOC + ',' + LAB1 + ',' + LAB2 + ',' + LAB3 NOT LIKE '%ra%'
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/232af/2/0)

Comment: Please check a case when `ENGLISH` having value `'r'` and `MATHS` having `'a'`.

Comment: @techdo - we don't know if `'r'` is a possible grade ....it is not in the `OP` data

Comment: This will cause a very slow performance on a large table, comparing values on concatinated columns is not a good solution