# How can I combine these 2 SELECTs into a single one?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to combine these two SQL statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14094327/how-to-combine-these-two-sql-statements)

I have 2 SQL queries.  They get counts based the variable equals either `CMSUID` or `CASUID` value in the table.  Otherwise, they are exactly the same.  How can I combine them into a single query, perhaps using a `CASE` statement.

```
select @cntCM_CNF = count(distinct(c.ID_Case))
from dbo.Cases c
join dbo.vew_CasePersonnelSystemIDs vcps on c.ID_Case = vcps.ID_Case
join hearings h on c.ID_Case = h.ID_Case
where vcps.CMSUID = @nSUID
    and h.HearingDate > getdate()
    and h.OnCalendar = 1 and h.Scheduled = 1
    and dbo.fn_HearingConfirmedNoHOs(h.ID_Hearing) < 2

select @cntCC_CNF = count(distinct(c.ID_Case))
from dbo.Cases c
join dbo.vew_CasePersonnelSystemIDs vcps on c.ID_Case = vcps.ID_Case
join hearings h on c.ID_Case = h.ID_Case
where vcps.CASUID = @nSUID
    and h.HearingDate > getdate()
    and h.OnCalendar = 1 and h.Scheduled = 1
    and dbo.fn_HearingConfirmedNoHOs(h.ID_Hearing) < 2
```

I can't figure out how to combine them because the result is a count of distinct items. Not sure how to make that happen.

Comment: You shouldn't try. The `WHERE` clauses are different, meaning that you will not be able to be certain that a combined query will result in the correct data being aggregated and returned.

Comment: @marc_s It is similar - in fact, I asked it.  But, the solution is not the same at all

Comment: Can `CASUID` and `CMSID` ever have the same value on the same record?

Comment: @BobDuell Yes, in fact, 90% of the time the values will be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is it...

```
select 
    @cntCM_CNF = count(distinct case when vcps.CMSUID = @nSUID then c.ID_Case else null end),
    @cntCC_CNF = count(distinct case when vcps.CASUID = @nSUID then c.ID_Case else null end)
from dbo.Cases c
join dbo.vew_CasePersonnelSystemIDs vcps on c.ID_Case = vcps.ID_Case
join hearings h on c.ID_Case = h.ID_Case
where 
    h.HearingDate > getdate()
    and h.OnCalendar = 1 and h.Scheduled = 1
    and dbo.fn_HearingConfirmedNoHOs(h.ID_Hearing) < 2 AND
    (vcps.CASUID = @nSUID OR vcps.CMSUID = @nSUID) --<<<<added for performance reasons
```

Comment: +1 This is what I was thinking.

Comment: I would add (vcps.CASUID = @nSUID OR vcps.CMSUID = @nSUID) to the WHERE clause for performance reasons (especially if those columns are indexed).

Comment: ok - agreed - I'll edit. I assume the reason for this is that the engine has a tendency to process the `WHERE` clause before assessing what is in the `SELECT`?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look about how UNION works.

Essentially, you'll select one count in one column, 0, and then 0,  in the other.

You probably need to use `UNION ALL`

```
select @cntCM_CNF = count(distinct(c.ID_Case)) AS Col1, 0 As Col2
from dbo.Cases c
join dbo.vew_CasePersonnelSystemIDs vcps on c.ID_Case = vcps.ID_Case
join hearings h on c.ID_Case = h.ID_Case
where vcps.CMSUID = @nSUID
    and h.HearingDate > getdate()
    and h.OnCalendar = 1 and h.Scheduled = 1
    and dbo.fn_HearingConfirmedNoHOs(h.ID_Hearing) < 2
UNION ALL
select 0 as Col1, @cntCC_CNF = count(distinct(c.ID_Case)) AS Col2
from dbo.Cases c
join dbo.vew_CasePersonnelSystemIDs vcps on c.ID_Case = vcps.ID_Case
join hearings h on c.ID_Case = h.ID_Case
where vcps.CASUID = @nSUID
    and h.HearingDate > getdate()
    and h.OnCalendar = 1 and h.Scheduled = 1
    and dbo.fn_HearingConfirmedNoHOs(h.ID_Hearing) < 2
```

Comment: This works, but it doesn't really combine it into a single logical query.  I am attempting to alleviate some perf issues by having go through all these tables once, rather than twice.

Comment: @AngryHacker - Don't assume that combining them will make it more performant.  You are filtering by different fields, and so should be using different indexes to do so in each query.  Performance tube each one individually.  If you want help on *that* give a detailed Schema for the tables used, and as much description about the relationships and behaviour of the data.